# Structuring sequences of longer operations in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider a sequence of steps that need to be performed as part of preparing a heavy web page:

```
step1();
step2();
..
stepk();
```

Each step may take in the range of 100milliseconds to a few seconds: but we are uncertain in advance how long each step takes.

At least until `Promise`/ `await` hit the street my understanding is that we use callbacks along with `setTimeout`.

But how can we avoid that from quickly becoming unwieldy?  In the following sequence we have two concerns:

- how to specify the timeout when the actual work could be up to two orders of magnitude in range
- how to handle the passing of arguments - `argK` in the code shown below - to the nested function invocations

First two steps (of K):

```
function step1(args1,args2,args3,..) {
  // do work for step1 using args1
  setTimeout(function() {step2(args2,args3);}, [some timeout..]);
}

function step2(args2,args3,..) {
 // do work for step2 using args2
 setTimeout(function() {step3(args3 [, args4, args5 ..]);}, [some timeout..]);
}
```

So how can these sequential steps be structured so that we are not sending a growing list of `args` down an entire chain of functions?

Note: `Webworkers` may be a useful approach for some cases: but I want to be able to serve from the local file system and that apparently precludes them:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-web-workers-to-speed-up-your-javascript-applications

> Restricted Local Access
>
> Web Workers will not work if the web page is being served directly
>   from the filesystem (using file://). Instead you will need to use a
>   local development server such as XAMPP.

Comment: If the tasks are that long, have you considered putting them into a WebWorker to prevent blocking the render thread? Inside the worker, you would not have to split the task and hence there would be no need to collect the arguments.

Comment: @Sirko  Thx for the thought.  Webworkers can not access the local file system `file:///`  and my app needs that.

Comment: Promises and async/await already *have* hit the street. Why don't you just use them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*we use `setTimeout`*". What for? To further slow down your tasks?

Comment: @Bergi  `With es2017, async/await is just around the corner. `  So *that* part of my statement is justified  https://medium.com/@bluepnume/even-with-async-await-you-probably-still-need-promises-9b259854c161    But it seems `Promises` have been around for some time.  I have not touched javascript for many years so am just learning about these things.  Feel free to add an answer using both approaches: the `async/await` for when it is common in browsers and the `Promises` that seem to be prevalent already.

Comment: @javadba Unfortunately that article is outdated - ES2017 is here already, since, er, its approval last week :-) You should use `async`/`await` to write new code (but start learning promises without the syntactic sugar). If you think it's not supported commonly *enough* (only you can decide this for your target group), use a transpiler and/or a polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

Without promises or async await, you must do it callback hell style

```
function step1(a,b,c){
  setTimeout(() => {
    step2():
  }
}
```

Or you can pass references to the next step

If step2 relies on results from step1

```
function step1(a,b,c, done){
  setTimeout(() => {
    done(a,b,step3):
  }
}
function step2(d,e,done){
  setTimeout(() => {
    done(e):
  }
}

step1("cat","dog","mouse", step2);
```

If you want to pass args to step2 manually, and get results from step1

```
function step1(a,b,c, done){
  setTimeout(() => {
    done(a):
  }
}
function step2(d,e,done){
  return function(step1a){
    setTimeout(() => {
      done(step1a, d):
    }
  }
}

step1("cat","dog","mouse", step2("d","e", step3);
```

This is probably as clean as you can get without Promisifying your async actions or implementing your own promise style.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading up on [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and it seems they could be a vanilla JS solution.

[Alex Perry wrote a great article](https://alexperry.io/javascript/2015/09/17/es6-generators-and-asynchronous-javascript.html) with a relevant demo:

```js
function step1() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        gen.next('data from 1')
    }, 500);
}

function step2(data) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        gen.next(`data from 2 and ${data[0]}`)
    }, 700);
}

function step3() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        gen.next('data from 3')
    }, 100);
}


function *sayHello() {
    var data = [];
    data.push(yield step1());
    data.push(yield step2(data));
    data.push(yield step3(data));
    console.log(data);
}

var gen = sayHello();

gen.next();
```

In the example above each asynchronous request returns a fake data. Each successive step receives an array containing the previous responses so the previous responses can be used.

Comment: Looks interesting: am trying it out now.

Comment: I've updated the example to be a bit more relevant. Disclaimer, I'm just starting my own learning into generator functions so this could be an incorrect use.

Comment: A generator does not help anything here.

Comment: Can you be more constructive in your feedback @Bergi?

Comment: I'm still not sure what the OPs problem is so I cannot suggest anything better, but generators should not (or: no longer) be used as a mediocre polyfill for `async`/`await` syntax. If it's a syntax support thing, that's the job of a transpiler.